# Грамотно отправить форму

Tags: php, yii2

Есть задача, в админке из БД читаются данные и отображаюстся в большом `table`. Таблица внутри формы. Заказчик хочет редактировать строку, ставить галочку только там где отредактировал и нажимать кнопку подтверить. То есть если на странице 50 строк, на 3 ставят галочку и только 3 изменяется в БД. Я ломал голову часа 3, ничего лучше не придумал кроме вот:
Это `view`:

```
   <form method="post" action="/varka">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Сервер</th>
            <th>Рейты</th>
            <th>Хроники</th>
            <th>Статус</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Принять</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($serverList as $serverValue):?>
            <tr>
                    <td><?=$serverValue['serverName']?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="<?=$serverValue['rates']?>"/>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select name="<?=$serverValue['id']?>['idGameVersion']">
                            <?php foreach (\app\models\Server::getServerList() as $value): ?>
                                <option <?php if($value['id'] == $serverValue['idGameVersion']) echo "selected" ?>  value="<?=$value['id']?>"><?=$value['versionCode']?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>


                        <select name="<?=$serverValue['id']?>['idServerStatus']">
                            <?php foreach (\app\models\Server::getServerStatuses() as $value): ?>
                                <option <?php if($value['id'] == $serverValue['idServerStatus']) echo "selected" ?>  value="<?=$value['id']?>"><?=$value['statusName']?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name="<?=$serverValue['id']?>['dateOff']" class='datepicker-here' value="<?=$serverValue['dateOff']?>"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <input type="url" name="<?=$serverValue['id']?>['serverURL']" value="<?=$serverValue['serverURL']?>">

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="<?=$serverValue['id']?>['success']">
                        <input type="hidden" name="<?=$serverValue['id']?>['idServer']" value="<?=$serverValue['id']?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить">
    </form>.
```

По нажатию кнопки я ловлю вот так пост запрос:

```
if($request->isPost)
{
    $post = $request->post();

    $data = array_filter($post, [$this, "filterPostdata"]);
}.
```

В `data` остаются только те данные, которые были отмечены чекбоксом, массив отсеивается по имени чекбокса. Вообще все работает и устраивает, но выглядит все жестким говнокодом, подскажите люди добрые как правильно решаются такие задачи?

Comment: Решается практикой ).

Comment: Была у меня похожая задачка. Пришлось выбрать из JS отмеченные чекбоксы и отправить аяксом запрос. К тому же если много данных (а у меня их было много) то зачем выполнять лишнюю работу отсылая их все на сервер, когда можно отсылать лишь необходимые?

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос. Насколько я помню, если данные не изменялись, то `save()` не произойдет. Yii2 сравнивает новое значение атрибута со старым, если разница есть, тогда сэйвит. Получается в данном случае можно обойтись без чекбоксов.